# Is there a way I could select from the query results and automatically populates the order sheet in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

I have a master sheet where I maintain product name, price, categories.

I also have a category sheet where I maintain various categories.

I want to create an order sheet but I first want to have a query table and from the result of query table, I want to be able to select it and put it in the order sheet. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot many ways you can do that. `VLOOKUP` , `QUERY`, Using `apps script` or any other programming languages. Which method do you want to use?

Comment: As Madhurjya said there are multiple ways & also it would be better if share a copy for your sample sheet with your problem & what you want to achieve

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqeoHBXb2toF22BobKm_UAtLRLS2LanBozKPki83k14/edit#gid=1256434762

Comment: How do I attach the google sheet here?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqeoHBXb2toF22BobKm_UAtLRLS2LanBozKPki83k14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @MKEN! I tried to open the Sheets that you shared but they inform me that I don't have access. Could you please make them public so I can try to help you? You can learn how to do that [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqeoHBXb2toF22BobKm_UAtLRLS2LanBozKPki83k14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqeoHBXb2toF22BobKm_UAtLRLS2LanBozKPki83k14/edit?usp=sharing   --- please check this, I am not sure if I did the right sharing settings.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqeoHBXb2toF22BobKm_UAtLRLS2LanBozKPki83k14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have not shared your sheet correctly yet.  To make it easiest to help you, it must be shared so anyone with the link can edit.

Comment: @MKEN We can't see your Sheet because it isn't public. Please, go to [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822) guide and follow the steps on *Share a file publicly* so we all can help you.

Comment: Hi sir, it seems like the sharing of google-suite is complicated. May I have your email address so I could share the link? Thank you.

Comment: @MKEN Please tell me where you find difficulties on the sharing process and I'll help you.